# Troubling understanding simple diode circuit

Tags: diodes

[image]

Assuming that the diode is OFF, the following affirmations come:

[image]

I can't understand the affirmation that Vd can't be positive... Where does that come from?

Comment: Did you mean "can't be positive"? The reason is that it isn't a voltage source (at least not in any meaningful sense).

Comment: Exactly, sorry.

Comment: But when I apply KVL I'm able to get +RI on resistances depending on the direction, why not in this case?

Comment: "Depending on the direction" is... a bit misleading. Numerically you can, but if you tried to do that in the actual model then your math wouldn't work.

Comment: So I can't get a voltage increase through a resistor? It seems obvious but I just want to confirm. So I can just use KVL to calculate the values, but the factors don't necessarily represent the actual voltages, is that right?

Comment: Currents and voltages are directional even if the components aren't.

Comment: If that's an ideal diode \$V_d\$ can't be positive because either the diode behaves like a open-circuit, if \$V_d<0\$ or it baheves like a short-circuit if \$I_d>0\$, and a short-circuit has no voltage drop on it.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand the affirmation that Vd can't be positive... Where does that come from?

Because the diode is only "off" when Vd is negative. So if you find that Vd is positive, it contradicts your initial assumption that the diode is off.

In the comments you asked,

> So I can't get a voltage increase through a resistor?

You can, but only in proportion to the current through it. Since you assumed the diode is "off", there is no current flowing through the diode. Then, by KCL, there is no current flowing through the resistor. So, by Ohm's law, the voltage across the resistor must be 0.